# существует ли утилита для удобного ограничения скорости интернет соединения

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, поиск-программ, трафик

необходимо выявить минимальную скорость интернета для удобного пользования конкретным компьютером. Хотелось бы найти простой способ это сделать, что то в роде утилиты которая позволила бы мне ограничивать скорость соединения передвигая ползунок мышкой или вводя в  консоль конкретное значение например 350Кб\с или 700.

Comment: [и](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28198/110559) т.д. [и](https://superuser.com/q/60344/454489) т.п.

Comment: Как вариант, использовать [Сквид](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ClientBandwidthLimit), в нем можно задать индивидуальные настройки по IP / пользователю / включать лимит после превышения трафика, и т.п. Плюс он может кешировать HTTP трафик.

Comment: @TotalPusher если я установлю эту программу на компьютер сможет ли она ограничить скорость подключения на нём и на сколько будет точность ограничения в плане величины скорости.

Comment: Я перечитал вопрос. Для вашего случая лучше то что посоветовали в первом комменте, так проще. Сквид - это больше для корпоративного сектора, а не личного. И там куча настроек, с этим придется разбираться.